# d'Alembertian inconsistency

Tags: spacetime, speed-of-light, conventions, units, absolute-units

I'm reading The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume II, Chapter 25. I'm confused as to why the d'Alembertian is defined in there as follows (Page 25-7, Eq 25.20):

$$ \Box^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} - \nabla^2 $$

But on Wikipedia, it is defined as:

$$ \Box = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} - \nabla^2 $$

The impression I got from Wikipedia is that $ \Box $ and $ \Box^2 $ mean the same thing, but why is the $ \frac{1}{c^2} $ present in the Wikipedia entry and not in the Feynman Lectures book?

Comment: $c$ is usually taken to be 1 in physics book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's resolved by a **change of variables**:

$$t_\mathrm{new} = ct$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t_\mathrm{new}} = \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_\mathrm{new}^2} = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$$

Setting $t$ to $ct$ can be very useful in some contexts, specifically general relativity and studying radiation. This is effectively identical to the different approach of setting $c = 1$

Comment: I have also found it very useful pedantically to write $w = c~t$ and then explain that $(w, x, y,  z)$ are our spatially-dimensioned coordinate axes.